# Removing empty key value pair from an object in javascript

Tags: javascript, json, object

How do i remove an empty key value pair from an object
like

```
obj = {name: 'asd','':'',pass: true}
```

is to be made `obj = {name: 'asd',pass: true}`

Thanks in advance

Comment: you are welcome. Thanks for sharing your issue with us. When do you plan to show us what you have tried and where do you get stuck at?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this `delete obj[''];`

More about `delete` operator:
https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/delete

Answer (score 1):

you can simply try :

```
delete obj[''];
```

Answer (score 1):

In one line:

```
delete obj[''];
```

or

```
 for(property  in obj){ 
   if(property == ""){
   delete obj[property]
   }
 }
```